# Black: formatting of fluent method calls

Tags: fluent, python-black

I'm using the `black` formatter, and I'm having trouble getting it to respect my wishes for fluent method chains like this:

```py
            result = (
                data
                .some_method()
                .some_other_method(arg1, arg2)
                .yet_another_method_with_longer_name(arg3)
            )
```

, which gets reformatted by `black` as

```py
            result = data.some_method().some_other_method(arg1, arg2).yet_another_method_with_longer_name(arg3)
```

.

The docs (at https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/the_black_code_style/current_style.html#call-chains) are pretty terse on the subject, saying

> *Black* formats those by treating dots that follow a call or an indexing operation like a very low priority delimiter. It’s easier to show the behavior than to explain it.

It may be easier for the *writer*, but not for the *reader* - I don't get it. =)

I'm looking for something like the ["magic trailing comma"](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/the_black_code_style/current_style.html#the-magic-trailing-comma) to tell the formatter that I desire one method call per line, so please format it that way.  But of course, an actual comma is not valid in this situation, it would turn the right-hand-side into a tuple.

I tend to think of `#fmt: on/off` as a very last resort, so I would prefer to avoid using them if at all possible.  Because of the libraries I'm using (and writing), there would be a *lot* of them in the code.